# What does the variable *read-eval* do?

Tags: clojure

I cam across this code from a remoting function (clojurescriptone) where the data sent back from the browser is being read. My question is what is the significance of setting the read-eval to false is ?

> (binding [*read-eval* false] (read-string data))

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a security measure so the browser cannot send code to be executed in the server. For example if the client/browser send `"#=(eval (System/exit 1))"` and *read-eval* is true, the server process will exit, which is probably something that you don't want.

See the difference of behaviour:

```
(binding [*read-eval* false] (read-string "#=(eval (System/exit 1))"))
(binding [*read-eval* true] (read-string "#=(eval (System/exit 1))"))
```

Also see the docs on [*read-eval*](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/%2aread-eval%2a).

Comment: The `eval` will confuse people.  The point is that the expression after the #= is evaluated when `*read-eval*` is true.  No need to use eval.

Answer (score 5):

The main purpose of `*read-eval*` is to allow the reader to evaluate an expression at read time, typically for something that doesn't have a literal notation.  If `*read-eval*` is true (the default), `read` and `read-string` will evaluate the expression following #=.  You can see how that feature is used when `*print-dup*` is bound to true -- meaning that you want values to print in a way that their precise types are preserved, in which case you'll see some values print with #= notation.  The default for `*print-dup*` is false -- for most things the standard Clojure notation is fine.  For example, we don't normally care about the distinction between Integers and Longs.

The `*read-eval*` feature is useful for loading code, but it creates a security risk when used with untrusted input.  The usual advise before Clojure 1.5 was to bind `*read-eval*` false when dealing with user input.  However, there were still some issues with reading Java objects that might cause problems.  That's fixed in Clojure 1.5.  More importantly, Clojure 1.5 introduced, `clojure.edn/read` and `clojure.edn/read-string` which do not support any of the `*read-eval*` features.  They're safe for reading user input representing the usual Clojure values as defined by the EDN format.  See http://edn-format.org for more information.

Comment: The issues you speak of with regards to reading Java objects, are those potential security risks?